# Any performance difference using variable name syntax vs. not using this syntax in Power Query?

Tags: powerquery, m, powerbi-datasource

I'm using Power Query to build a pseudo data warehouse using data from two large transactional databases. This requires a ton of querying to merge and append tables and performance is slow. I am using the following technique to reduce the number of dependencies to the data sources: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSEj_cb9F_w (Using the Power Query Reference Feature to Reduce Query Dependencies). My question is: is there a performance difference when I reference these data sources using the M variable syntax or not? For example:

Variable Syntax:
let
Source = #"Example Data Source"
in
Source

"Non-Variable" Syntax:
let
Source = Example Data Source
in
Source

I don't see a difference in the Query Dependencies view, but I wonder if there is an underlying performance difference that I don't know how to measure.
I also noticed you could reference parameters either way.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer here: https://radacad.com/basics-of-m-power-query-formula-language

Variable Names 
Name of variables can be all one word, like Source. or it can has spaces in it. in case that you have some characters such as space, then you need to put the name inside double quote (“) and put a hashtag at the beginning of it(#). something similar to:

#"This is a variable name"